# PyQt QRC resource icons missing

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpushbutton

this is my `qrc_resources.qrc` file

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC><RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
<file alias="fault.png">images/fault.png</file>
<file alias="schedule.png">images/schedule.png</file>
<file alias="inventory.png">images/inventory.png</file>
<file alias="setting.png">images/setting.png</file>
<file alias="test.png">images/test.png</file>
<file alias="te.png">images/fault.png</file>
<file alias="local.png">images/local.png</file>
<file alias="newfault.png">images/newfault.png</file>
<file alias="newschedule.png">images/newschedule.png</file>
<file alias="viewschedule.png">images/viewschedule.png</file>
<file alias="lock.png">images/lock.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

this is my `pyqt code`

```
newfault = QtGui.QPushButton(QtGui.QIcon(":\newfault.png"),"Add \nNew Fault")
newfault.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30,30))      
viewfault = QtGui.QPushButton(QtGui.QIcon(":\viewfault.png"),"View Faults")
viewfault.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30,30))
```

but the images doesn't show up in the QPush Button. What is causing the problem?

FYI, i did import qrc_resources file and not all the png files are missing.If i use some of the images in resource file (for example, settings.png) it showed up on the button. If i use `fault.png,test.png`, nothing show up.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my bad! i was using `:\` to import from qrc_resources. In fact, i have to use  `:/` .